# Almacenamiento en listas con elementos repetidos

Tags: python, lista, almacenamiento

Estoy haciendo un programa y por mi poco conocimiento he necesitado crear una lista con los elementos repetidos:

```
días_de_semana = ['lunes', 'martes', 'miércoles', 'jueves', 'viernes', 'sábado', 'domingo', 'lunes', 'martes', 'miércoles', 'jueves', 'viernes', 'sábado', 'domingo']
```

Tengo entendido que el total de almacenamiento de esa lista es igual al de esta lista:

```
días_de_semana = ['lunes', 'martes', 'miércoles', 'jueves', 'viernes', 'sábado', 'domingo']
```

Ya que, por ejemplo, el elemento días_de_semana[0] se guarda en el mismo espacio de días_de_semana[7].
Eso solamente lo leí, pero no estoy seguro, si alguien sabe que lo que estoy diciendo es correcto me lo podría confirmar.

Y también si alguien sabe si en esa lista (la primera, la que tiene los elementos repetidos) se puede liberar espacio o hacer que se vea mejor estaría agradecido, muchas gracias.

Comment: Python almacena sólo una vez cada cadena constante (como "lunes"), sin importar cuantas veces aparezca dentro del programa. La lista misma requiere espacio constante por cada elemento, para almacenar un puntero al contenido (en este caso, a la palabra "lunes").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando Python lee un script, procesa todos las cadenas almacenando sólo una copia de cada una.

Al asignar la misma cadena a distintas variables, todas apuntan a la misma cadena:

```
a = "lunes"
b = "lunes"

print(a is b) => True
print(id(a)) => 140383615769904
print(id(b)) => 140383615769904
```

La función `id` retorna el identificador interno único del objeto (en realidad, es el puntero a memoria). Si dos objetos tienen el mismo `id`, significa que son el mismo objeto con dos nombres distintos.

El operador `is` verifica si ambas variables se refieren al mismo objeto, en cuyo caso retornan `True`. O sea, es una forma compacta de verificar que ambos objetos tienen el mismo `id`.

En el ejemplo, ambas variables, `a` y `b` se refieren al mismo objeto, son idénticas y por tanto, iguales.

Dos variables pueden ser iguales (tener el mismo contenido), pero no idénticas (apuntan a distintos objetos):

```
a = "lunes"
b = "LUNES".lower()

print(a, b)   => lunes lunes
print(a is b) => False
print(a == b) => True
print(id(a))  => 140547986455856
print(id(b))  => 140547986455920
```

Esto porque al leer el script, `a` recibe una constante, pero `b` recibe una expresión, que no es evaluada hasta después. El resultado es que `a` y `b` son objetos distintos, pero sus contenidos son iguales.

Python puede evaluar expresiones constantes al momento de leer el script, como en este caso:

```
a = "lunes"
b = "lun" + "es"

print(a is b) => True
print(id(a)) => 140059731913840
print(id(b)) => 140059731913840
```

En resumen, sólo habrá una copia en memoria de cada cadena constante, sin importar cuantas veces aparezca en el código fuente.

**Listas**

Cuando creas una lista, está sólo almacena los `id` de los objetos, sin importar el tamaño de los objetos mismos:

Para saber cuanta memoria ocupa un objeto cualquiera en Python usas la función `sys.getsizeof()`, que retorna el número de bytes usados.

En este ejemplo tenemos dos listas con 10 elementos de distinto tamaño cada una. Ambas listas ocupan el mismo espacio en memoria, el que no incluye el espacio de los elementos mismos.

```
import sys
lista1 = ["lunes"] * 10
lista2 = ["toda la semana escribo Python"] * 10
print(sys.getsizeof(lista1)) => 136
print(sys.getsizeof(lista2)) => 136
```

**Resumen**

Python se encarga de todos los detalles truculentos y administra con eficiencia la memoria.

Tus listas no necesitan ningún cambio.

Answer (score 2):

El espacio que ocupan los datos guardados en una lista se descompone en dos factores:

- El espacio que ocupa cada dato en sí. Una cadena como `"lunes"` ocupa en python 54 bytes. `"martes"` ocupa 55 (parece que es función de cuántas letras tiene, más una cantidad fija).
- El espacio que ocupa dentro de la lista cada una de las referencias a los datos.
- El espacio ocupado por la "parte fija" de la lista (información que Python necesita para manejar la lista en sí, al margen de que pueda estar vacía, con metadatos como cuántos elementos hay, etc).

En tu caso tienes dos listas diferentes:

```
lista1 = ['lunes', 'martes', 'miércoles', 'jueves', 'viernes', 'sábado', 'domingo', 'lunes', 'martes', 'miércoles', 'jueves', 'viernes', 'sábado', 'domingo']
lista2 = ['lunes', 'martes', 'miércoles', 'jueves', 'viernes', 'sábado', 'domingo']
```

Las palabras en sí (los nombres de los días de la semana) se almacenan aparte de las listas. Las listas sólo contendrán referencias a esos nombres almacenados en otra parte. Por tanto los nombres, de lunes a domingo, ocupan una cantidad de memoria fija independientemente de si son referenciados desde la lista1 o desde la lista2 (o de si son referenciados más o menos veces). Podemos calcular cuánto ocupan en sí los días de la semana:

```
from sys import getsizeof
memoria_ocupada = sum(getsizeof(dia) for dia in lista2)
```

y salen 437 bytes.

Aparte de eso, cada lista ocupa un espacio adicional "por ser lista" y otro espacio que depende de cuántos elementos contiene:

```
getsizeof(lista2) --> 128
getsizeof(lista1) --> 184
```

Vemos por tanto que `lista1` ocupa más que `lista2` por tener más elementos, y en realidad da igual si esos elementos son cadenas, enteros, objetos o lo que sea, ya que lo único que guarda la lista son referencias a esos objetos, y todas las referencias ocupan siempre lo mismo sin importar el tipo al que referencien.

No obstante la forma en que CPython implementa las listas es mediante un array de punteros. Por motivos de eficiencia, el array es mayor que el número de elementos que tiene la lista, para que se puedan añadir más elementos sin necesidad de tener que redimensionar ese array.

Así una lista vacía está implementada internamente como un array con sitio para 0 elementos. Tan pronto como añadas uno, Python incrementa ese array para que quepan 4 elementos. De ese modo las tres siguientes inserciones no necesitan que el array se redimensione. Al insertar un quinto, Python vuelve a hacer crecer el array para que quepan ahora hasta 8 elementos. La cantidad en que incrementa el array en estos ejemplos es de 4 en 4, pero no siempre es así. A medida que la lista crece Python presupone que cada vez serán necesarios más elementos, por lo que luego aumenta el tamaño de la lista en 8 más, y más adelante en 32, etc.

Debido a esto puedes encontrarte con cosas como que una lista de 5 elementos ocupa la misma memoria que una de 8 elementos. El siguiente código lo demuestra:

```
lista = []
for i in range(20):
  print(len(lista), getsizeof(lista))
  lista.append("otro")
```

Salida:

```
0 72
1 104
2 104
3 104
4 104
5 136
6 136
7 136
8 136
9 200
10 200
11 200
12 200
13 200
14 200
15 200
16 200
17 272
18 272
19 272
```

Así, el último caso corresponde a una lista con 19 elementos, todos iguales (la palabra "otro"), y ocupa 272 bytes, (la palabra "otro", que está aparte, ocupa 56 más). Pero una lista con 17 repeticiones de "otro" también ocupaba 272 bytes, como se ve en la salida. Y una lista con 17 elementos todos diferentes entre sí, también ocuparía 272 bytes (aunque luego, cada uno de esos elementos, tendría su propia ocupación de memoria).